# Is there a way to kill a program while in Linux command line?

Tags: linux, command-line

I'm currently testing a C++ program on the command line of a linux machine and unfortunately it sometimes gets into infinite loops.  Is there a way that, from the command line, I can kill this program?

Comment: Like CTRL-C or with kill?

Comment: How 'bout kill -9 pid

Comment: http://blog.geeksaresexytech.netdna-cdn.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/10/linux-evil.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`CTRL-C` is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 3):

```
pkill myAppName
```

Answer (score 2):

get the PID of the process:

```
  ps -ef | grep <the name here>
```

then,

```
  kill -9 <PID>
```

Answer (score 2):

`ps aux | grep "name of program" | cut -d ' ' -f 2 | xargs kill -9`

is a nice oneliner for this.

Answer (score 1):

`ps -aux | grep "name of the program"`

will give you the id of the program
and then:

`kill -9 <id of the programm>`

Answer (score 1):

or try `killall -9 myAppName`.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `ps` command to learn the PID of your program's process, then `kill` to terminate the process.

Comment: How can I run these commands while my program is still looping?

Comment: You can use control-Z to put your program in the background. But really, you should always have more than one shell when you're doing "real work" on a text-based interface. What if you need to look at one piece of code while you edit another?